# Def file and cpp file compilation

Tags: c++, function, dll, compiler-errors

I am trying to generate a dll file.
I have two file

```
DefFile.def
LIBRARY "square"
EXPORTS 
square
```

\

```
funct.cpp 
double __stdcall square(double & x)
{    
    return x*x; 
}
```

the project has the name square and it's a Dll project in Visual studio 2015.

When trying to compile funct.file alone it works. But when trying to compile the project square I got two errors :

> Erreur    C2143   erreur de syntaxe : absence de ';' avant
>   'chaîne'  square  c:\users\hasna\desktop\projet
>   vba-c++\square\square\deffile.def 1

and

> Erreur   C4430   spécificateur de type manquant - int est pris en compte
>   par défaut. Remarque : C++ ne prend pas en charge int par
>   défaut    square  c:\users\hasna\desktop\projet
>   vba-c++\square\square\deffile.def 1

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

The DEF file syntax requires at least a space before the function names e.g.

```
EXPORTS
    square
```

However, the name in the DEF file is the *decorated* name of the function (see [Decorated Names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56h2zst2.aspx)) which in this case would be something like `?square@@YGNAAN@Z`.

Since you are using VC++ the easiest way to export a function is not via a DEF file, but [Exporting from a DLL Using __declspec(dllexport)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx):

```
__declspec(dllexport) double __stdcall square(double & x);
```